# How to extract paragraph values in html when having multiple <p>?

Tags: xpath

I need to extract address, telephone using xPath from my html page.
My html code is:

```
<div class="info-block-value"> ==$0
   <p>36 rue de la Verrerie 75004 PARIS</p>
   <p>Tél : 0111 222 222</p>
  </div>
```

I tried with,
   "xPath": "descendant::div[@class='info-block-value']/p
   But it shows me an error, as a newbie to xPath can someone help me?
   Also provide me a good tutorials, links etc.

Comment: `//div[@class='info-block-value']` should give you the address and phone nuber. Are you expecting then in 2 different lines or any specific format?

Comment: This two values must store in two columns, yeah as u said in two different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the xpath.

Address:

```
(//div[@class='info-block-value']/p)[1]
```

Phone Number:

```
(//div[@class='info-block-value']/p)[2]
```

Comment: Parser[1] attribute[1] store Addr has invalid XPath descendant::div[@class='info-block-value']/p)[1]

Comment: you don't need `descendant::`

Comment: By the way, I'm doing crawler code ( in jason format), and I try to enter this code under "modelAttribute": []

Comment: Can you please add your code and tool set to original post.

Comment: It was my mistake, your code is working, thanks, BTW can you refer me some tutorials whose having such examples for the beginner like me.

Comment: Here is the link for the [xpath 1.0 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) which will give you enough knowledge to start with.

Comment: Great tutorial!! Thanks

Comment: Can I modify this question pls?

Comment: Please post another question, if you have a different question.

Comment: Yeah I have already posted with the title "How to use OR logical operator for multiple <p> in xPath? "